# How to join two dataframes by different fields in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, the following is the content of each one.

df1:

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+--------+                  
|line_item_usage_account_id|line_item_unblended_cost|    name|
+--------------------------+------------------------+--------+
|              100000000001|                   12.05|account1|
|              200000000001|                    52.0|account2|
|              300000000003|                   12.03|account3|
+--------------------------+------------------------+--------+
```

df2:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------------+------------------------+
|accountname|accountproviderid|clustername|app_pmo|app_costcenter|line_item_unblended_cost|
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------------+------------------------+
|   account1|     100000000001|   cluster1| 111111|      11111111|                   12.05|
|   account1|     100000000001|   cluster1| 666666|      55555555|                   10.09|
|   account1|     100000000001|   cluster7| 666660|      55555551|                   11.09|
|   account2|     200000000001|   cluster2| 222222|      22222222|                    52.0|
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------------+------------------------+
```

I need to find only the id that is in df1.line_item_usage_account_id and if it is not in df2.accountproviderid and add the fields df1.line_item_unblended_cost and df1.name as follows:

df3:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------------+------------------------+
|accountname|accountproviderid|clustername|app_pmo|app_costcenter|line_item_unblended_cost|
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------------+------------------------+
|   account1|     100000000001|   cluster1| 111111|      11111111|                   12.05|
|   account1|     100000000001|   cluster1| 666666|      55555555|                   10.09|
|   account1|     100000000001|   cluster7| 666660|      55555551|                   11.09|
|   account2|     200000000001|   cluster2| 222222|      22222222|                    52.0|
|   account3|     300000000003|   null    | null  |      null    |                   12.03|
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+--------------+------------------------+
```

This is the code for the dataframes, any idea how to achieve it?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession   
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    [100000000001, 12.05, 'account1'], 
    [200000000001, 52.00, 'account2'], 
    [300000000003, 12.03, 'account3']], 
    schema=['line_item_usage_account_id',  'line_item_unblended_cost', 'name' ])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['account1', 100000000001, 'cluster1', 111111, 11111111, 12.05],
    ['account1', 100000000001, 'cluster1', 666666, 55555555, 10.09],
    ['account1', 100000000001, 'cluster7', 666660, 55555551, 11.09],
    ['account2', 200000000001, 'cluster2', 222222, 22222222, 52.00]], 
    schema=['accountname', 'accountproviderid', 'clustername', 'app_pmo', 'app_costcenter', 'line_item_unblended_cost'])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have PySpark installed to check, but it could help

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.line_item_usage_account_id==df2.accountproviderid, how='left').filter(col('df2.line_item_usage_account_id').isNull())
```

It is left to join with filtering, but if your df could be huge - need to use another approach

Comment: Hello amarynets, I tried the left join but it generates an error.
This is the line:
`
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.line_item_usage_account_id == df2.accountproviderid, how="left").filter(col(df2.accountproviderid).isNull())
`

Comment: This is the error that it generates, thank you very much for your answer.
`
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:276)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
`